# Understanding Python multiple assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, assignment-operator

Consider this assignment statement example:

```
>>> x, y = x[y] = {}, None
>>> x
{None: ({...}, None)}
>>> y
>>>
```

What is the value assigned to `x` and how does this assignment work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement assigns the value on the far right to each target to its left, starting *at* the left. Thus, it's equivalent to

```
t = {}, None
x, y = t
x[y] = t
```

So, `t` starts out as a tuple consisting of an empty `dict` and the value `None`.

Next, we unpack `t` and assign each part to `x` and `y`: `x` is bound to the empty `dict`, and `y` is bound to `None`.

Finally, we can assign the tuple to `x[y]` as well, since we just defined `x` and `y`. The key `None` is added to the `dict` referenced by `x`, and its value is the original tuple. Thus, we've made `x[y]` refer to `x` itself: a cycle!

Python can detect this cycle, so it shows the `dict` as `{...}`, rather than trying to expand it infinitely to `{None: ({None: ({None: ...`.